# Listener class doesn't has effect on TableViewer?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I've made a class that implements Listener. This listener controls the resize of my JFace Table Viewer in my RCP view, however, since I've implemented the listener in a different class, nothing happens when the table is resized, why is this happening?

My listener:

```
public class TableResizeListener implements Listener {

TableViewer viewer;
TableColumnLayout layout;

public TableResizeListener(TableViewer viewer, TableColumnLayout layout) {

    this.viewer = viewer;
    this.layout = layout;

}

@Override
public void handleEvent(Event e) {

    TableColumn[] colunas = viewer.getTable().getColumns();

    layout.setColumnData(colunas[0], 
            new ColumnWeightData(50, 100, true));

    layout.setColumnData(colunas[1], 
            new ColumnWeightData(50, 100, true));

}
```

}

The simple code in the view:

```
// resize listener
    table.addListener(SWT.RESIZE, new TableResizeListener(tableViewerCustos, tableCustosLayout));
```

Thanks in advance, Polska :)

Comment: Use `TableColumnLayout` on a `Composite` containing the table viewer to deal with resizing - see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html (section 2.4)

Comment: I'm already doing it.. as you can see my variable 'layout' is a TableColumnLayout variable. I've solved my problem however, thanks anywawy

Comment: @polska Post your answer, and also accept it. Don't leave the solution in the question itself.

Comment: If you are using TableColumnLayout the resize should be handled automatically

Comment: @greg-499, that's right, but if you, per example, resize a column in real-time execution, then when you resize the table everything will scale properly but that column you've resized will not scale its size to the default you set in the table creation.. And that's what my listener does, it scales every column size to its default values.

Comment: @GGrec, yes, I will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed my eventType to `SWT.Resize`, instead of `SWT.RESIZE`, and now the listener is working fine.